# I opened android project but project can get SDK-tools

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

In MainAcitivity i am using `Tools.systemBarLolipop()` it is function from Tools.java file 
in Tools.java there is `window.setStatusBarColor(global.getIntDarkColor());`
comes from window.java 
in window.java all android.annotation import are error

Comment: Please ask question more specific way. It is difficult to understand what do you want actually. thank you.

Comment: when i run application i get error in MainActivity when i debug i found all imports 
android.annotation error and annotation is part of SDK-tools

Comment: i am editing on old project SDK of the project is 27 but in android studio is 29 i installed SDK 27 and run the project i get error when i do debugging the application stop Tools.systemBarLoipop()